# iPhone system sounds in my bundle

Tags: iphone, audio

I would like to use the system sounds (Marimba, Ascending, Bark etc) as local notification sounds in my app.  As I can't access these directly, can anyone tell me where I can get .aiff files for these sounds that I can include in my bundle?

Comment: Using a search engine with the right combination of words will sure help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use those without explicit permission. There are, however, CC licensed sounds available from resources such as [the Freesound project](http://freesound.org) you can use in your app (subject to respective licenses).

Comment: Ok this has now become 2 questions                                    1. Does anyone have any definite answer as to whether or not the system sounds can be re-used in an app?                     2. Does anyone have any decent sounds that I can use instead (not poor quality recordings of other sounds which is all else I can find)?